# Find duplicate objects and add values to them

Tags: powershell, for-loop

Have a file.csv:

```
id,location_id,name,title,email,directorate
1,1,Amy Lee,Singer,,, 
2,2,brad Pitt,Actor,bpitt@example.com,Production 
3,5,steven spielberg,Producer,Screenwriter, spielberg@example.com,Production
4,8,Andy lee,Comedian,,Radio
```

Have a script:

```
$inputFile = Import-Csv -Path $filePath
$text = (Get-Culture).TextInfo

foreach ($line in $inputFile) {
    $name = $line.name
    $line.name = $text.ToTitleCase($name)
    $firstName = $line.name.split(" ")[0]
    $lastName = $line.name.split(" ")[1]
    $line.email = ($firstName[0] + $lastName + $line.location_id + "@abc.com").toLower()
} 

$inputFile | Export-Csv $fullPath
```

Need to add *location_id* only when *email* equals, example:

```
id,location_id,name,title,email,directorate
1,1, Amy Lee,Singer,alee1@example.com,, 
2,2,Brad Pitt,Actor,bpitt@example.com,Production 
3,5,Steven Spielberg,Producer,Screenwriter,sspielberg@example.com,Production
4,8,Andy Lee,Comedian,alee8@example.com,Radio
```

I know that need to use **for loop**, but I don't understand what the structure should be in it.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "Need to add location_id only when email equals" ?

Comment: "when email equals", when it's blank or when the last names match?

Comment: I apologize for the incomprehensible wording of the problem, my English is not that good. I meant that the location is added only if the same email is formed from the first letter of the first and last name, for example: Amy Lee, Andy Lee at the output of the script alee@example.com, but these are duplicates and in this case need to add the location_id, example alee1@example.com, alee8@example.com

Answer (score 1):

you can use compare-object to get the duplicates and later a if statement to to only add location_id if mail is in the list of duplicates.

```
$inputFile = Import-Csv -Path $filePath
$text = (Get-Culture).TextInfo
#get duplicates, filter only values where the property email is specified
$inputFileMail = $inputFile | ?{$_.email}
$duplicates = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $inputFileMail -DifferenceObject $inputFileMail -Property email -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru | Sort-Object -Property email -Unique

foreach ($line in $inputFile) {
    $name = $line.name
    $line.name = $text.ToTitleCase($name)
    $firstName = $line.name.split(" ")[0]
    $lastName = $line.name.split(" ")[1]
    #Verify if duplicates contains email
    If ($duplicates.email -contains $line.email){
        $line.email = ($firstName[0] + $lastName + $line.location_id + "@abc.com").toLower()
    }
    Else {
        $line.email = ($firstName[0] + $lastName + "@abc.com").toLower()
    }
} 

$inputFile | Export-Csv $fullPath
```

Comment: It give me error: 
$duplicates = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $inputFileMail -Differe …
     |                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ReferenceObject' because it is null.

if i understand the condition correctly, checking for duplicate mail occurs before email is created (the email address is formed from the first letter of the first name, last name and @abc.com), so inputFileMail is empty. Maybe I'm wrong

Comment: right.... thought the csv contains the information and the email gets rebuild... I'll update the code

Comment: you only want to generate a email address for those that have not already one defined - rigth?

Comment: Tested script, working as not expected.
I need to generate an email anyway (my original script did just fine) from a combination of the first letter of the first name, last name, and @abc.com. location_id is added only if there is a duplicate from this bundle, example Amy Lee, Andy Lee at the output of the script alee@abc.com, need to be alee1@abc.com and alee8@abc.com

Comment: clarification on the problem above